# RequestParameter encoded string

Tags: spring, controller, get, encode, http-request-parameters

I have a controller with a RequestParam as a String, which is BASE64 encoded, and it includes many times the "+" character (something like "domain.com/request?code=sdfesdfd+23fewrfr3"). When I try to print the 'code' value whitin the controller method body, it prints the value replacing the "+" for a space " " (in the example, "sdfesdfd 23fewrfr3"). How can I avoid having this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Run the string through the URLEncoder if you can...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

... if you can't do that, try using percent encoding....

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: I didnt solved this issue as ia had to change the codification assets and i stopped having urls like the given previously

Answer (score -1):

A replace of all spaces with '+'?

```
 code.replaceAll(" ", "+");
```